# Python does not loop over the file when piped in

Tags: python

I have a python file that's supposed to iterate via splitting lines but it only shows the first line and does not iterate.

Command that I run:

```
MINGW64 ~/Desktop (master)
$ cat input.txt | python deneme 16:20
1/30
```

Input.txt:

```
30 1
45 *
* *
* 19
```

Code: Deneme.py

```
#  Getting the list input
str_list = input().splitlines();

for i in str_list:
    minute = i.split()[0]
    hour = i.split()[1]
    print(hour + "/" + minute)
```

Solution:

```
import sys

for i in iter(sys.stdin.readline, ''):
   minute = i.split()[0]
   hour = i.split()[1]
   print(hour + "/" + minute)
```

Comment: Just noticing something, not an answer: you have an `import sys` in your code, but you do not seem to use it anywhere.

Comment: Piping into a script doesn't give information on `input()` - that's reserved for console keystrokes. You should read `stdin`

Comment: when you pipe, it creates a stream which send the data line by line, as you only consume once with input, it'll never send then next lines

Comment: @DevLounge this is what I had in mind till barny said it's reserved for console keystrokes, can someone provide a resource about this ?

Comment: you indeed should consume stdin, it's the proper way of doing it. input is usually used for humans inputs

Comment: for i in iter(sys.stdin.readline, ''): sorted the issue

Comment: Please dont edit your questions to include the solution. Instead post as an answer below

Answer (score 2):

Piping is basically taking `stdout` of a process into `stdin` of another process. Which implies that you should read the `stdin` from `sys` that you've imported.

For example

```
import sys
for line in sys.stdin:
   ...
```

I've absolutely no clue why `input` doesn't work and I didn't find any resources on this particular thing, I've encountered it before so I just know.

Answer (score 0):

[`input()` only reads one single line at a time](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input), so in order to read multiple lines, you have to call it repeatedly. In order to read the entirety of stdin, call it in an infinite loop. It should raise an `EOFError` once all the lines have been read.

```py
while True:
    try:
        minute, hour = input().split()
        print(minute + "/" + hour)
    except EOFError:
        break
```

```sh
$ python3 test.py <input.txt
30/1
45/*
*/*
*/19
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this :

```
import sys
    
with open('input.txt') as file:
    for line in file:
        minute = line.split()[0]
        hour = line.split()[1]
        print(hour + "/" + minute)
```

Comment: this does not help, the OP want to make it work using pipe